# how does notepad++ save file to the disk

Tags: notepad++, text-editor

I have a query regarding how notepad++ or any other text editor saves the file to the disk? I saw Scintilla editor code, and saw that it opens a file handle by doing fopen and calls fwrite with the buffer present in the editor. Does the notepad++ also write the contents of the file the same way?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be so, based on the [writeFileContent](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/blob/58fa70b5808592533adc1224daa783fe39837f8e/PowerEditor/src/MISC/Common/Common.cpp) function found in their GitHub sources.

However, they do have other areas/use of the fwrite, check [this search](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/search?l=C%2B%2B&q=fwrite%28&type=)